# How to evaluate Riemann Sums where x is an exponent.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, riemann-sum

I just need to know how I would go about evaluating this:

## $$
\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}  v^t\frac{(1-v^t)}{i} =  \frac{1}{i}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}  v^t(1-v^t) 
$$

## $$
=\frac{1}{i}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}  v^t - \frac{1}{i}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}v^{2t} $$

How would I evaluate this? I really cannot seem to figure out how the Riemann sums would look for both t and 2t as the exponent.

Comment: The index of summation, $k$, doesn't appear in any of your formulas.  Is this a mistake?

Comment: my bad just fixed it i meant to write t @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: @saulspatz just fixed it. i meant to write t=0

Comment: The two sums at the end are geometric, so you probably know a formula for them.

Comment: For the first part Rieman sum of v^t I get the geometric series 1/1-v which turns out to be this function for annuities-due but the second one where its 2t I am stumped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (geometric) sum is $\frac{1-v^n}{1-v}$  Your answer is correct only if $|v|\lt 1$ and upper limit is $\infty$

Second sum is also geometric $=\frac{1-v^{2n}}{1-v^2}$

The difference (for $|v|\lt 1$ and $n\to \infty$) is $\frac{v}{1-v}$ not $1$, unless $v=0.5$.

Comment: ahh ok. and yes v = (1/1+i) so raising v to any power that is greater than or equal to 1 will be less than 1. thank you.

Comment: For $v=\frac{1}{1+i}$, $\frac{v}{1-v}=-i$.  Your original expression (for $n\to \infty$) seems to have  an extra factor of $i$.